# Jsoup with advanced websites

Tags: java, jsoup

considering I am newbie with jsoup and know only fundamental stuff about html/css, I'm curious how could I make my life easier when trying to parse something from Facebook. For instance I want to return all my available wall posts from my own wall... What is the procedure to determine what I have to return.

So target is:

```
<div class="_wk mbm">
    <span class="userContent"> FOOBAR text i posted yesturday!!! </span>
</div>
```

But facebooks huge layout is a problem for me... Is there a way to determine the selectors target via da `ìnspect element` in chrome or in mozilla?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Jsoup you cant get all elements of a given class:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("...").get();
System.out.println("title: " + doc.title());

/* here: all <span> with class=userContent */
Elements userContents = doc.select("span.userContent"); 
for (Element span : userContents) {
    System.out.println("User Content: "+span.text());
}
```

Comment: Edit: the correct method is `element.text()` and not `element.getText()`.